# Distance between two nodes in a tree weighted

Tags: algorithm, graph, lowest-common-ancestor

My Question is very straight forward.

> A weighted tree is given. We must find the distance between two given nodes.

since number of queries are very high(around 75000) each time bfs be timed out so I tried different way to do that.

**My algorithm is like this :**

- I ran dfs from vertex 0 and calculated distance from root(0) to all vertex something like this

  ```
      depth[v]=depth[u]+w,where u is parent of v and w is weight b/w (u,v)
  ```
- Once I calculated depth of all node using dfs and 2^j th parent of each node(Assume I know how to do that).I calculated **LCA for (u,v)** asked for each query.
- Then I calulated distance like this

  ```
      distance between (u,v)=depth[u]+depth[v]-2*depth[lca(u,v)]
  ```

But I am not getting correct verdict as expected.**Is my algorithm correct or am I missing something crucial**.Guidance needed :)

P.s  Incase anyone wants to see my implementation-Link http://paste.ubuntu.com/13129038/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach sounds reasonable, but looking at the linked code I suggest you try a small example (e.g. with 3 nodes in the tree) and check the contents of the parent array carefully.

As far as I can see, the only lines changing the contents of the parent array are:

```
memset(parent,-1,sizeof parent);
```

and

```
parent[i][j]=parent[i-1][parent[i-1][j]]
```

so I believe the contents of parent will always equal -1.

Perhaps you need a base case setting parent[0][j] equal to the parent of j?

Also, it is not quite clear from the code whether you are using depth to mean a count of the number of edges, or a sum of the weights of all the edges.  For the distance calculation to work you need a sum of weights, but for the LCA algorithm to work you may find you need to use the count of edges.

Comment: Hi sir I just saw that I overlooked base case of parent array so thanks for that but still its not getting correct might be some other mistake.I found this correct solution for the problem but I cannot see why I am wrong or my algorithm is wrong can you help after seeing this http://paste.ubuntu.com/13129663/

Comment: Hi sir,thanks for your time.I have finally solved this problem.Actually fault that I was making is calculating LCA with weight which was rubbish.I used another array for depth of nodes and calculated LCA with that(foolish me :p ).Thanks for your time (implementation -http://paste.ubuntu.com/13142974/) +1 for you time.